# NSString inheritance

Tags: objective-c

I'm doing an **useless** thing for my first step in Obj-C

```
@interface String : NSString
{
  int m_isnull;
}

- (id) init;
- (int) isNull;
@end


@implementation String

- (id) init
{
 self = [super init];

  m_isnull=1;
  return self;
}

- (int) isNull
{
  return m_isnull;
}

@end
```

test :

```
String *a;

a=@"ok";
```

Works fine, but just 2 little questions
1) When I'm compiling I have this warning

```
warning: incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct NSString *', expected 'struct String *'
```

I don't know how to avoid it !?

2) a=@"ok" is a fastest way to initialize a string, but when I'm debugging, I don't stop by at my init constructor why ?

Comment: Subclassing `NSString` is something experienced Cocoa developers never do.  I would heartily recommend not doing what you're doing.

Comment: Indeed Dave. But it's a common pitfall for new Obj-C Developers :)

Comment: Of course it's useless as I said In the post... !!!

Comment: http://serenity.uncc.edu/web/ADC/2005/Developer_DVD_Series/April/ADC%20Reference%20Library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/Classes/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154/397865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@"ok"` is an NSString object. You're creating an instance of the superclass and trying to assign it to a subclass pointer. Think of subclassing as an "is-a" relationship.  In your example, `String` is an `NSString`. `NSString` is *not* a `String`.  Therefore, you can't assign an `NSString` object to a `String` pointer.

Comment: Thanks man, your answer is cool (better than just saying "don't do that")

Answer (score 3):

`@"ok"` is actually a NSString like `1` is an integer. That's why you get this compiler warning.

> There are also @"" NSString literals.
>   It is essentially shorthand for
>   NSString's +stringWithUTF8String
>   method. Mac Player
>   already stated that it is used to
>   distinguish this sort of string
>   literal from a char * string literal
>   in C.

Source http://guides.macrumors.com/Objective-C_Tutorial#The_.40_symbol

Normally you would create a [Category](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) in Objective-C to extend the `NSString` Class.

Comment: Not so "evident", because using 2 different types lead to a warning, sure, but here the class override the same type...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `NSString` class reference:

> It is possible to subclass NSString (and NSMutableString), but doing so requires providing storage facilities for the string (which is not inherited by subclasses) and implementing two primitive methods. The abstract NSString and NSMutableString classes are the public interface of a class cluster consisting mostly of private, concrete classes that create and return a string object appropriate for a given situation. Making your own concrete subclass of this cluster imposes certain requirements (discussed in “Methods to Override”).

If you really want to add an `-isNull` method to NSString you would probably be better off adding it as a category.

I think you might also want to try writing `-(BOOL) isNotBlank` instead. Consider what happens if you call `-isNull` on a nil pointer, is that the return value you would expect?